# jaxl counld not connect openfire via bosh

Tags: xmpp, openfire

When I'm running the following code, it comes an error (Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in E:\wamp\www\chat\vendor\abhinavsingh\jaxl\xep\xep_0206.php on line 123). But when i comment out the line ( 'bosh_url' => 'http://test.com:7070/http-bind',), it seems to be fine. could anyone tell me what's wrong?

```
 <?php

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$client = new JAXL(array(
    'jid' => 'devin@localhost',
    'pass' => 'like',
    'bosh_url' => 'http://test.com:7070/http-bind',
    'log_path' => __DIR__ . '/logs',
    'log_level' => JAXL_INFO,
    'strict' => false,
));

$client->add_cb('on_auth_success', function() {
    global $client;
    echo 'on_auth_success', '<br/>';
    $client->set_status("available!");  // set your status
    //$client->get_vcard();               // fetch your vcard
    //$client->get_roster();              // fetch your roster list
});


/*$client->add_cb('on_chat_message', function($msg) {
    global $client;
     echo 'on_chat_message', '<br/>';
    // echo back
    $msg->to = $msg->from;
    $msg->from = $client->full_jid->to_string();
    $client->send($msg);
});

$client->add_cb('on_disconnect', function() {
    _debug("got on_disconnect cb");
});
*/

$client->start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Because PHP is waiting for the process. You can run it in terminal: `php XXX.php`. Add the line:

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

which gives no timeout.

Comment: Did you mean `set_time_limit(0);`? If you want, click [edit] to update answer.